# How to get external IP broadcast when IP is changed?

Tags: android, ip

I have an external IP.
and I want that IP when ever it changes.
I couldn't identify what is wrong here?

I've used this method to get IP broadcast

```
 public static String getExternalIpAddress(){
    try{
        for(Enumeration<NetworkInterface> ene = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); ene.hasMoreElements();){
            NetworkInterface infte = ene.nextElement();
            for(Enumeration<InetAddress> enumextIpAddr = infte.getInetAddresses(); enumextIpAddr.hasMoreElements();){
                InetAddress inetExtAddress = enumextIpAddr.nextElement();
                if(!inetExtAddress.isLinkLocalAddress() && inetExtAddress instanceof Inet4Address){
                    return inetExtAddress.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (SocketException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: What has your code to do with receiving a broadcast?